# How can I introduce pagination in meta with laravel responder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-response

I use the following code with Laravel Responder:

```
 return responder()->success(Service::paginate(5), ServiceTransformer::class)->respond();
```

Laravel Responder is a package for building API responses.
And I get this response:

```
    "status": 200,
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "value": 1,
            "label": "Angular"
        },
        {
            "value": 2,
            "label": "PHP"
        },
        {
            "value": 3,
            "label": "Drupal"
        }
    ],
    "pagination": {
        "count": 3,
        "total": 4,
        "perPage": 3,
        "currentPage": 1,
        "totalPages": 2,
        "links": {
            "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/service/list?perPage=3&page=2"
        }
    }
```

I want to include pagination in meta, is there a way to do this? example

```
meta:  { 
"pagination": {
        "count": 3,
        "total": 4,
        "perPage": 3,
        "currentPage": 1,
        "totalPages": 2,
        "links": {
            "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/service/list?perPage=3&page=2"
        }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: `responder` is not a built-in Laravel function, so it'd be helpful if you indicated which library you're using there.

Comment: This one? https://github.com/flugger/laravel-responder Look into a response decorator, if so. https://github.com/flugger/laravel-responder#decorating-response

Comment: thanks man, sorry for disturbing